# Invoking a dll function without a call in the main

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, dll, runtimemodification

I want to know how can we call a function that is defined in external static class (dll file) without a call to it in main.

To make things clearer, consider an exe file of which code is not exposed and we cannot do any sort of modifications to it, now I want to test a exe file with certain test cases that are defined in my dll file for which a call to the function must me made within the main() function of the exe file. But as mentioned, I dont have permission to modify the code of exe file. Now how this dll function is invoked at the required pointof execution without a call to it using visual studio.

I want to call a function without adding any line to main function.

To make things clearer ,I just want to add some  example

```
static class DllClass
{
   static void dllFunction()
   {
      //some implementation.
   }
}
class ThirdParty
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    //Default implementation that i cannot modify.
    //Invoking my static function at this point without calling.(i.e i cannot call DllClass.dllFunction()) 
    //continuing with default implementation.
  }
}
```

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking.  Can you show some code examples, or maybe a diagram?

Comment: So you want to call a dll from an exe without having the access to modify the exe?

Comment: @rory.ap I added an example please check with it

Comment: @Richard Boyce    YEAH ! to some extent i want to call a function in dll from an exe without modifying main in the exe file (in visual studio )

Comment: Are you trying to build your first code injection exploit?

Comment: @dymanoid  yes indeed it is kind of injecting some code in main

Comment: Is there a way to acheive it?

Comment: @GANESH GANI, How about using the Powershell in your side as a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

One idea is that using the Powershell call the dll file if you couldn't modify the code in the .exe.

For example, a simple library with methods.

> namespace Math
>   {
>   public class Methods
>   {
>       public Methods()
>       {
>       }
>       public static int Compare1(int a, int b)
>       {
>         if (a
>       return a;
>         else
>       return b;
>       }
>
> public int Compare2(int a, int b)
>          {
>         if (a
>       return a;
>         else
>       return b;
>            }
>        }
>   }

And then call it in the Powershell Environment:

[void][reflection.assembly]::LoadFile("C:/xxx.dll")
02.[Math.methods]::Compare1(10,8)
03.$a=New-Object Math.Methods
04.$a.Compare2(2,6)